# Steps needed to connect with H2 database with Play framework 2.0

Tags: java, h2, playframework-2.2

I'm new to Play framework and wants to connect H2 database with my application.

Could some one please explain the steps that are needed to configure H2 database with Play 2.2 framework (like, downloading drivers, adding dependency etc in detail (or) in step by step manner).